# Creating world choropleth in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, data-visualization

I am trying to create a choropleth map in Google Maps to visualize some international country-level statistics. It will be an add-on to an existing Google Maps application.

I searched around and found these potential solutions:

- **[Cartographer.js](http://cartographer.visualmotive.com/)** has the ability to overlay vector-based choropleth maps directly on Google Maps. However, it only supports US states.
- **[Fusion Tables](https://www.google.com/fusiontables)** can also be used to create choropleth overlays ([example](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/embedviz?viz=MAP&q=select+col1+from+1YHQBsKPsnytQt6n2zy_ks5r8RFBjPqnODxvFlL8&h=false&lat=17.62365070527682&lng=-20.834000000000035&z=3&t=1&l=col1)). However, this adds complexity because data is maintained outside of my database. I also have to obtain and maintain country boundaries data.
- **[Demographics Layer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/demographics)** would have been perfect, but it is for Business customers only. Plus, it is limited to US geography.

*So my question is...* Is there a better way to do this in Google Maps JavaScript v3?

P.S. I just came across **[jVectorMap](http://jvectormap.com/)**. It looks promising ([example](http://jvectormap.com/examples/world-gdp/)), except that it is just a standalone map. It would be nice if I can somehow combine the jVectorMap functionality with the Google Maps interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an author of jVectorMap could say that combining of its functionality with Google Maps would be really painful. I think the best solution here would be creation of colorful polygons in GM by hand.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I agree with you. It's just quite cumbersome to manually draw those polygons (once I obtain all the coordinates). And on some computers, a map with complex polygons tends to become laggy. I mentioned jVectorMap because it's simple and fast.

Comment: Drawing vector polygons in Google Maps turned out to be rather easy, and the performance is much better than I expected. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You would be best to go with one of these plugins:

http://leafletjs.com/
or
http://polymaps.org/